# problems with fmt:massage tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, tags

I update my page elements via ajax and I faced dificulty: my fmt:message tag doesn't work if I set it in javascript.

on jsp page (works fine)

```
<div id="div">
  <fmt:message key="search_select_country"/>
</div>
```

but after javascript (doesn't):

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key=\"search_select_country\"/>";
```

**P.S.** in such way all works fine:

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "It works";
```

**Question**: Why fmt:message doesn't work? and how can I fix it?

Comment: in first case it generate code: 
<div id="div">
  <fmt:message key="search_select_country"></fmt:message>
</div>

in second (when set inerHTML in javascript):
<div id="div">
country:
</div>

why it doesn't calculate fmt:message value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not put a backslash before the double quote:

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key="search_select_country"/>";
```

or, if you want it clearer

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key='search_select_country'/>";
```

Comment: tried:
1. document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key=search_select_country />";
2. document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key='search_select_country' />";
3. document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key=\'search_select_country\' />";

also generate html code:
<fmt:message key="search_select_country"></fmt:message>

Comment: also tried 
var country = search_select_country;
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<fmt:message key=" + country + "/>";

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use fmt:message in a .js file, out of a JSP?

Comment: yes, I try to set fmt:message tag into div.innerHTML in .js file.

Comment: .js files are not processed by the JSP engine. They're served as is by the web browser. JSP tags can only be used in JSPs.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to update fmt:message tag via AJAX. Is it right?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense to me. fmt:message is a server-side, JSP tag, producing a message. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: My site must be multilanguage. And when I choose on of the languages, my AJAX response must set innerHTML due to language, that had been choosed. For example, I want to update my <select tag via AJAX: options always puuled from DB, but there is the first option like 'choose country'. This first option should change due choosen language. How can I achieve it?

Comment: An AJAX request is not different from another, regular request. Generate HTML using a JSP and use the fmt:message tag to translate the static strings. Where's the problem?

Comment: What you mean by 'Generate HTML using a JSP'? Please, more details.
P.S. I handle response (that pull data from DB in javascript). How can I generate there HTML using JSP?

Comment: Handle your AJAX request exactly as you would handle any other request: by forwarding to a JSP which contains HTML markup and JSP tags.

Comment: Yes, I have generated my HTML in ControllerServlet with help of PrintWriter. But I hear that PrintWriter on the server side - bad practice. As I understand I MUST pass my ArrayList(pulled from BD) to JSP page and only there form my html.

Comment: So now you're saying that you're using JSP tags inside a servlet? JSP tags are **JSP** tags. They must be used in JSPs. Generating HTML in servlets is indeed a bad practice. JSPs should be used to generate HTML. That's what they're for. It really seems you should read a book or tutorial about servlets and JSPs, because you're missing basic concepts.

Comment: Yes, I know ) I'm going to read Head First JSP, but say me please:
Should I use PrintWriters on the Server side in my case (DAO MVC)?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Generating HTML in servlets is indeed a bad practice. JSPs should be used to generate HTML. In MVC, V means View. A servlet is a controller, not a view. A JSP is a view.

Comment: As I understand I can generate JSP only if I reload the whole page (compile my servlet). Is it wrong? But I'm using AJAX.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. As I already said, an AJAX request is no different from a regular request. And a JSP can generate whatever you want: a full page or a portion of a page. Read that book.

Comment: Please, little example of generating jsp in AJAX

Comment: As I already said, an AJAX request is no different from a regular request. A JSP is a JSP. Whether it's executed to answer to an AJAX request or to a regular request doesn't matter. Read that book.